# How to customize React Antd table header with table data?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to customer header table like it:

[image]

Comment: antd table cell supports colSpan and rowSpan that set in render return object. [check here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/demo/colspan-rowspan.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the cells as below:

```
const columns = [
  {
    // title: "Title",
    colSpan: 1,
    // dataIndex: "tel",
    render: (value, row, index) => {
      const obj = {
        children: value,
        props: {}
      };
      if (index === 0) {
        obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
      }
      if (index === 1) {
        obj.props.rowSpan = 0; // merge here
      }
      return obj;
    }
  }
];
```

Refer: ant document of [components-table-demo-colspan-rowspan](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-colspan-rowspan)